# CiviRules is not tagging users or adding them to groups

Tags: civirules

Civi 5.13.5, Drupal 7.67.

Hey everyone,

I've set up a number of CiviRules to help automate the process and add people to groups / tag them based on the types of events they attend, so they get added to our different mailing lists.

We're having issues with two of our CiviRules.

**Volunteers**

[image: Volunteer CiviRules]

As above: we have events that are marked as "Volunteer Inductions". People who are marked as having attended these events are meant to get added to the Volunteers group/mailing list, removed from the EOI group, and have a tag added.

None of these actions happen, despite all the conditions being fulfilled. The actions are all set to have 'no delay'.

**Event Attendees**

[image: Event Attendees]

As above: when people are marked as having "Attended" a certain event, they are meant to be added to a corresponding group/mailing list.

However, again, despite meeting these conditions, this does not happen. The actions are set to have 'no delay'.

**

Does anyone know why this is happening or how we can fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the trigger "Event participant is added" and the participant status "attended", but if you have already added the participant as "registered" and then changed it to "attended" then this doesn't work. You would need to have a trigger "Event participant is changed". You might want two rules if you can go through a "registered" status first only in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that strikes me is the trigger is "participant is added". That means it is only done for new participants, not for existing ones. Should it not also do this for changes to participants?
Personally I have not done anything yet with the event participant trigger, so I would focus on testing that one first.

I do regularly use tagging of contacts and adding to group actions, so I know that these actually do work, the problem lies elsewhere. Next week we have planned a small CiviRules sprint, I will have a go with these examples.

Okay, here are my test results.

Test 1:
This is the rule I have entered (and apologies for the Dutch in some places):
[image: Rule participant added]

If I now register a contact for the event and immediately give them the status "attended" this works like a charm:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Obviously this will NOT work when I register a participant with the status "registered" and then later this is changed to status "attended" as the participant already exists, so the "participant is added" is not triggered. To deal with this I have a second rule on "participant is changed":
[image]

Again, this changed rule works like a charm.